# frames_to_video Python programme

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to write a programme to convert a set of frames to images. However, I am not getting the same smooth video but rather a continuous jump between frames. What I did was initially convert the video to frames and then convert back the frames to videos. My video is about 1 min long and has about 1500 pics (30FPS) so I can't think of anything wrong with my video-to-frames programme. Anyways I have attached my code below. The reason I am doing this is to apply FACE API to each frame and to blur each face(for the confidential purpose). Is there a better way? Or is there something wrong with my programme?

```
import cv2
import argparse
import os

# Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-ext", "--extension", required=False, default='png', help="extension name. default is 'png'.")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=False, default='output.mp4', help="output video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Arguments
dir_path = '******************'
ext = args['extension']
output = args['output']

images = []
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if f.endswith(ext):
        images.append(f)

# Determine the width and height from the first image
image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, images[0])
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow('video',frame)
height, width, channels = frame.shape

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') # Be sure to use lower case
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

for image in images:

    image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, image)
    frame = cv2.imread(image_path)

    out.write(frame) # Write out frame to video

    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("The output video is {}".format(output))
```

Comment: You said your video was 30 fps but VideoWriter object you use create videos with 20 fps? Also it could help if you also show how you converted your video to images.

Comment: You could also consider ffmpeg, which can be used as an executable tool to process videos to frames and back again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realised the problem lies with the images files not being in order.